# How are water-tight transmissions made, like the kind you see on inboard boats, pumps or food blenders?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, waterproofing, transmission

I want to replicate the kind of interface you see on inboard boats, pumps, or food blenders. Basically, I want put a motor in a sealed vessel, and have it turn a prop outside the vessel, in water.

Is this usually done just with a layer of grease over a bearing? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: The shaft going to the propellor on a boat goes through a bearing or bearings and seals...

Comment: I found the name on one of your other answers - essentially I want to build a stuffing box.

Comment: The term you want to search on is "rotating seal" (avoid the pages on dancing marine mammals).  A stuffing box is one sort of that larger category.

Comment: That's what I was after, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seal you are looking for is commonly called an oil rotary seal ring.

I found many brands and sizes with a quick search.

the range of prices for a 1-inch shaft is around $5.

[image: oil rotary seal]